# c/c++ NLP library

Tags: c++, c, nlp, open-source, pos-tagger

I am looking for an open source Natural Language Processing library for c/c++ and especially i am interested in Part of speech tagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [this POS Tagger list from Stanford](http://nlp.stanford.edu/links/statnlp.html#Taggers). Some of them are language independent and others are targeted at C/C++ or have specific bindings.
Not present on that list, but still important in my opinion is [Citar](http://www.danieldk.eu/code-citar), a C++ free software part of speech tagger using a trigram Hidden Markov Model.